# Why is dynamic memory not used in this case when using vector<>.push_back()?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I spotted a snippet of C++ code that goes like this:

```
// constructor that creates a 2D vector _store[nRow][nCol]
FlexiMatrix::FlexiMatrix(int nRow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++){
        _store.push_back( vector<int>() );    
        _store[i].push_back( 0 );
    }
}
```

And `_store` is declared as follows: `vector< vector<int> > _store;`

It seems to violate my understanding of local variables and the stack. Shouldn't the locally created vector's memory cease to exist the moment we exit this constructor? This is more so given that `vector<int>.push_back()` requires an alias reference as its input parameter, so the copy constructor is never invoked and what `push_back()` receives is the actual reference to the local variable?

Comment: push_back takes a constant reference, so the temporary local vector<int> you created doesn't get destroyed or a new one doesn't get created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **So the copy constructor is never invoked and what `push_back()` receives is the actual reference to the local variable?**

No.
`std::vector_push_back()` makes a copy of the passed object. The content of the object passed as parameter might be *copied/moved*(in C++11) to the newly created object.

There are two forms of `push_back()` since C++11:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

In your case, `vector<int>()` creates a temporary(r-value)and hence the second form will be used. This second form will *move* the content of the temporary to the new object which gets added to your vector. Hence, It will use the move constructor & not the copy constructor.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of the move constructor. It seems really interesting, thank you!